# How to filter objects contained in two Sets based on a single property without overriding equals() and hashCode()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, equals, hashcode

I have a *set* of objects and trying to find if an object exist in list by `id`. I do not want to override `equals()` and `hashCode()`.

```java
class ABC {
    Long id;
    String name;
}
```

I want to do the below statement without overriding `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods

```java
Set<ABC> abcSetOne;
Set<ABC> abcSetTwo;

abcSetOne.stream()
   .filter(abcSetTwo::contains)
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

`id`s are guaranteed unique.

I am using Java 8.

Comment: What is `relationshipsToFilter`?

Comment: @Ryan sorry updated. was giving example instead of real code

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I am trying to find if any elements that are exist in set one are present in set two. Also I will negate to see if any elements which are in set one are not in set two @Unmitigated

Comment: Does every combination of `id` and `name` expected to be unique?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko may not be. Only ids are gauranteed unique and i want filter/find based on only id

Comment: Also I am using java8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Objects equality based on a single attribute

When need set intersection (*in terms of set theory*) of your object based on **one attribute** only without changing the existing `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods, you can create a `HashSet` of `id`s.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<ABC> abcSetOne = Set.of(new ABC(1L, "first"), new ABC(2L, "second"), new ABC(3L, "third"));
    Set<ABC> abcSetTwo = Set.of(new ABC(1L, "first"), new ABC(5L, "fifth"), new ABC(3L, "third"));
    
    Set<Long> idsOne = abcSetTwo.stream()
        .map(ABC::getId)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    Set<ABC> result = abcSetOne.stream()
        .filter(abc -> idsOne.contains(abc.getId()))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output*

```
[ABC{id=1, name='first'}, ABC{id=3, name='third'}]
```

---

#### Objects equality based on multiple attributes

When you need to establish uniqueness based on **more than one object's property**, you can define a wrapper class with the `hashCode/equals` contract implemented based on these properties.

As a wrapper you can utilize of Java 16 record, that will make the code leaner (`hashCode()` and `equals()` will be generated by the compiler)

```
public record ABCWrapper(Long id, String name) {
    ABCWrapper(Wrapping.ABC abc) {
        this(abc.getId(), abc.getName());
    }
}
```

For earlier versions, `ABCWrapper` can be defined as a plain class.

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<ABC> abcSetOne = Set.of(new ABC(1L, "first"), new ABC(2L, "second"), new ABC(3L, "third"));
    Set<ABC> abcSetTwo = Set.of(new ABC(1L, "first"), new ABC(5L, "fifth"), new ABC(3L, "third"));
    
    Map<ABCWrapper, ABC> abcByWrapper = abcSetTwo.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(ABCWrapper::new, Function.identity()));
    
    Set<ABC> result = abcSetOne.stream()
        .map(ABCWrapper::new)
        .filter(abcByWrapper::containsKey)
        .map(abcByWrapper::get)
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());

    System.out.println(result);
}
```

*Output*

```
[ABC{id=1, name='first'}, ABC{id=3, name='third'}]
```

Comment: You can also use an ad-hoc key like `Arrays.asList(obj.getId(), obj.getName())` but a dedicated `record` is preferable.

Comment: and also the .collect(Collectors.toSet()); could be replaced to .toSet()

Comment: @Holger Interesting, that resembles a concept of tuple in TypeScript (just an observation).

Comment: @prostýčlověk That's not correct, there's no method `toSet()` defined in the `Stream` interface. You might be confusing it with Java 16 `toList()`. Sure, you can use a static import and write `collect(toSet())` (*maybe that you were trying to convey*), but it's nothing wrong with being explicit in the code, and personally I think that `collect(Collectors.toSet())` is a more preferred stile for the code snippets posted on the internet.

Comment: sorry my bad, yeah you're right.